# Sanitization for array with many urls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to sanitize many urls from array with video sites e.g.:

```
  videos: SafeResourceUrl = ['www.someURL1', 'www.someURL2',...
  ];
```

For this case I have made constructor like here:

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.videos[this.trackByMethod(this.count)] = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.videos[this.count]);
  }
```

To get position in the array I have made the method, which give me current index from template:

```
  trackByMethod(index: number): number {
    return this.count = index;
  }
```

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="videos" align="center" *ngFor="let vid of videos; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" (ondrag)="trackByMethod(i)">
  <iframe [src] = "vid"  style='min-width: 30%; height: 315px' allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the index from the template. My method trackByMethod with event binding from template `(ondrag)="trackByMethod(i)"` doesn't work (I have tried with many other interfaces of GlobalEventHandlers unsuccessful).

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
      videos: string[] = ['www.someURL1', 'www.someURL2',...
      ];
sanitizedVideos: SafeResourceUrl[];
    
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
this.sanitizedVideos =        this.videos.map(video =>  sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video);
      }
```

In your html

```
<div class="videos" align="center" *ngFor="let vid of sanitizedVideos; let i = index" (ondrag)="trackByMethod(vid,i)">
  <iframe [src] = "vid"  style='min-width: 30%; height: 315px' allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Now in your tackByMethod you have both the target video and the index (if needed)

Comment: Thanks, but it does't work for array of type SafeResourceUrl. If I remove the type from array, then I get the error: 'ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context'

Comment: If I remove the type of videos array then I get the error that this is the string: <code>TS2322: Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'.</code>

Comment: there is also change in the forEach loop .. where the sanitised value is now assigned back to the array

Comment: yes I know, it is strange, but the error exists in this moment after forEach loop: "=> video"

Comment: hmm .. try the update code .. i have made separate array for sanitised urls